# Using Window Handle to disable Mouse clicks using c#

Tags: c#

I need to disable the Mouse Clicks, Mouse movement for a specific windows for a Kiosk application. Is it Feasible in C# ?

I have removed the menu bar and title bar of a specific window, will that be a starting point to achieve the above requirement ? How can i achieve this requirement.

The code for removing the menu bar and title bar using window handle :

```
 #region Constants
    //Finds a window by class name
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    //Sets a window to be a child window of another window
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    //Sets window attributes
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    //Gets window attributes
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
    public static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetMenu(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetMenuItemCount(IntPtr hMenu);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool DrawMenuBar(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool RemoveMenu(IntPtr hMenu, uint uPosition, uint uFlags);

    //assorted constants needed
    public static uint MF_BYPOSITION = 0x400;
    public static uint MF_REMOVE = 0x1000;
    public static int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    public static int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000; //child window
    public static int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000; //window with border
    public static int WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000; //window with double border but no title
    public static int WS_CAPTION = WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME; //window with a title bar 
    public static int WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000; //window menu  
    #endregion

    public static void WindowsReStyle()
    { 
        Process[] Procs = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (Process proc in Procs)
        {
            if (proc.ProcessName.StartsWith("notepad"))
            {
                IntPtr pFoundWindow = proc.MainWindowHandle;
                int style = GetWindowLong(pFoundWindow, GWL_STYLE);

                //get menu
                IntPtr HMENU = GetMenu(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                //get item count
                int count = GetMenuItemCount(HMENU);
                //loop & remove
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                    RemoveMenu(HMENU, 0, (MF_BYPOSITION | MF_REMOVE));

                //force a redraw
                DrawMenuBar(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                SetWindowLong(pFoundWindow, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_SYSMENU)); 
                SetWindowLong(pFoundWindow, GWL_STYLE, (style & ~WS_CAPTION)); 
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Unplug the mouse and keyboard from the kiosk?

Comment: want to do this programatically

Comment: Are you writing the application ?...if so: What OS version ? What .net Version ? What client technology, winforms ? WPF ?

Comment: @ Rusty, It is WinXp, Dotnet Visual studio c# 2008, Framework 3.5, Winforms.

Comment: @srk, And you are writing the Kiosk application or trying to prevent input to an existing application ?

Comment: @Rusty, My application "A" will be getting the handle for another application "B" and remove the titlebar, menubar using the above code. Here i want to disable the Mouse and keyboards inputs for that application "B".
In the above sample i do it for notepad. Objective is, i dont want the user to key in any thing or click in that application "B" which has only one form.

Comment: @Rusty, I tried BlockInput Function, it disables the mouse and keyboard for whole system. i want to do it for specific FORM

Comment: @srk Got it :)...You are on the right track. SLaks just posted an answer that should get you there...so I won't post :) Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [EnableWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646291%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The description is:

> Enables or disables mouse and keyboard
>   input to the specified window or
>   control. When input is disabled, the
>   window does not receive input such as
>   mouse clicks and key presses. When
>   input is enabled, the window receives
>   all input.

So you would add

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnableWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool enable);
```

and

```
EnableWindow(pFoundWindow, false);
```

This is equivalent to setting the Enabled property on a Windows Forms Form/Control.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to override the WndProc and check for WM_MOUSE* events there. If you dont call the base WndProc for these handled events, it should work.
A point to consider here is that since yours is a kiosk application, will your special mouse handling lead to any problems for Touch screen.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent keyboard input in a window in another process, you need to [make a keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).
You can then check [`GetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) and suppress the input.

Comment: can be elaborate ?
Now i set the forgroundwindow to my application. How to suppress the input in the window now ?