# How to Get handle of a window and disable the Keyboard inputs using c#?

Tags: c#

How to Get handle of a window and disable the Keyboard inputs using c# ?

Comment: @SLaks Probably the same thing as this, two hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878989/using-window-handle-to-disable-mouse-clicks-and-keyboard-inputs-using-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent keyboard input in a window in another process, you need to [make a keyboard hook](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).
You can then check [`GetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) and suppress the input.

Comment: You cannot steal focus from another application.  Do you mean `get`?

Comment: DO u mean to say that, my requirement is not feasible ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Now i set the forgroundwindow to my application. How to suppress the input in the window now ?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            if (p.Length > 0)
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle);
            }

Comment: You can do that, but it's unlikely to work.  [You cannot steal focus from other programs](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/16/73780.aspx).

Comment: [Correct.  You cannot](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx).

Comment: Is there any Alternatve, u can suggest??