# Disable Mouse moves and clicks using c# windows application

Tags: c#

I want to Enable the Mouse moves and clicks Using c# windows application.
How to do this ?

I don't want to unplug my mouse from my PC. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Window Handle to disable Mouse clicks and Keyboard Inputs using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878989/using-window-handle-to-disable-mouse-clicks-and-keyboard-inputs-using-c)

Comment: "possible" duplicate of the last 3 questions asked by this user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the GUID of mouse and disable the mouse using c#

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/WindowsHookLib.aspx) to make a mouse hook that can suppress the mouse input.
You can then check [`GetForegroundWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) and set `e.Handled` to `true`.

Comment: i used the function GetForegroundWindow(), i need to know how to disable the inputs of mouse now..

Comment: Make a mouse hook, but don't call `CallNextHookEx`.

Comment: can u support me with any links to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I referenced the .dll to my application. But i find some difficulties in utilizing the .dll to disable mouse inputs. Because the source in Link is VB.Net which i dont understand. Can you help me calling the function form .dll ?