# How to stop mouse left button function on datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Mouse left button should be stop select or click when i edit cell in datagridview. i don't know how to disable mouse left button in windows application.

Comment: You don't disable the mouse buttons; you typically disable controls. Btw unclear what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Window Handle to disable Mouse clicks using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878989/using-window-handle-to-disable-mouse-clicks-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

you can manage the action in `MouseClick` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
   {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: When you edit the cell, `DataGridView` won't receive events, the editing control will.